# R Match rows in a data frame based on formula

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame containing 7 columns and I want to add a column with information about the 'parent-row'. This sounds vague, so I'll clarify with an example. Below you can see a data frame:

```
 `        Nclass0        Nclass1 BestSBestI impurity n
[1,]       5       5     4  36.0 0.2500000 10
[2,]       5       2     1  37.0 0.2040816  7
[3,]       4       0    -1  -1.0 0.0000000  4
[4,]       1       2     2   0.5 0.2222222  3
[5,]       1       0    -1  -1.0 0.0000000  1
[6,]       0       2    -1  -1.0 0.0000000  2
[7,]       0       3    -1  -1.0 0.0000000  3`
```

Using the nclass0 and nclass1, I want to add an 8th column in which matching pairs have the same id. The first row is the parent row (with id=0). The rows match if [rowX,1] + [rowY,1] are equal to the parents row nclass0 and [rowX,2] + [rowY,2] are equal to the parent rows nclass1. RowX and rowY are the child rows and should get id=1.

In this case the parent row [1,] has child rows [2,]&[7,] and these rows should get id=1. After this the second row becomes the parent row with its own child rows [3,] and [4,] with id=2, until all rows with child rows have been assigned an id.

I have made several attempts but failed miserably. Does anyone have a suggestion how this can be done? The desired output for this case would be:

```
`    Nclass0       Nclass1  BestS BestI impurity n id
[1,]       5       5     4  36.0 0.2500000 10  0
[2,]       5       2     1  37.0 0.2040816  7  1
[3,]       4       0    -1  -1.0 0.0000000  4  2
[4,]       1       2     2   0.5 0.2222222  3  2
[5,]       1       0    -1  -1.0 0.0000000  1  4
[6,]       0       2    -1  -1.0 0.0000000  2  4
[7,]       0       3    -1  -1.0 0.0000000  3  1`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes use of a `while` loop.  The loop will run until either every row has an `id` value, or until it has evaluated all of the rows in the data frame.  I'm sure there are some weaknesses, but it's a good start:

Note: I think this could get unbearably slow in a large data frame, so I hope you don't need to do this on anything large (each `outer` takes about 1 second to complete on a vector of 10,000).

```
DF <- 
  structure(list(Nclass0 = c(5, 5, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
                 Nclass1 = c(5, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3), 
                 BestS = c(4, 1, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1), 
                 BestI = c(36, 37, -1, 0.5, -1, -1, -1), 
                 impurity = c(0.25, 0.2040816, 0, 0.2222222, 0, 0, 0), 
                 n = c(10, 7, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3)), 
            .Names = c("Nclass0", "Nclass1", "BestS", "BestI", "impurity", "n"), 
            row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

DF[["id"]] <- c(0, rep(NA, nrow(DF) - 1))

i <- 1
while(sum(is.na(DF[["id"]])) > 0){
  cross0 <- outer(DF[["Nclass0"]], DF[["Nclass0"]], `+`)
  match0 <- cross0 == DF[["Nclass0"]][i] & lower.tri(cross0)

  cross1 <- outer(DF[["Nclass1"]], DF[["Nclass1"]], `+`)
  match1 <- cross1 == DF[["Nclass1"]][i] & lower.tri(cross1)

  rows <- as.vector(which(match0 & match1, arr.ind = TRUE))
  if (length(rows)) DF[["id"]][rows] <- i

  if (i == nrow(DF)) break else i <- i + 1
}
```

#### Explanation

To try to clarify your problem, you are looking for pairs where `x1 + x2 = x_ref` AND `y1 + y2 = y_ref`.

What this code does is make a matrix of all of the possible pairwise sums of a vector with itself.  This is accomplished with `outer`.

```
outer(DF[["Nclass0"]], DF[["Nclass0"]], `+`)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]   10   10    9    6    6    5    5
[2,]   10   10    9    6    6    5    5
[3,]    9    9    8    5    5    4    4
[4,]    6    6    5    2    2    1    1
[5,]    6    6    5    2    2    1    1
[6,]    5    5    4    1    1    0    0
[7,]    5    5    4    1    1    0    0
```

When trying to find the x-match for the first row, we compare this matrix to `DF$class0[1]` (and take set the upper triangle to false to avoid duplicates).

```
match0 <- cross0 == DF[["Nclass0"]][1] & lower.tri(cross0)
match0

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

We repeat this process for `Nclass1`

```
cross1 <- outer(DF[["Nclass1"]], DF[["Nclass1"]], `+`)
match1 <- cross1 == DF[["Nclass1"]][1] & lower.tri(cross1)
match1

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

To find the row indices, we want to find the intersection of these two `match` matrices--in other words `which` positions in both matrices are `TRUE`

```
as.vector(which(match0 & match1, arr.ind = TRUE))
[1] 7 2
```

So rows 7 and 2 are related to the first row.  We can repeat this operation for each subsequent row until we've assigned an ID for every row.

### Turning it into a function

Here's a function that takes a data frame, a column name for the x-match, the column name for the y-match, and a character to name the id variable.  I've added some bells and whistles to check the inputs.

```
assign_id <- function(DF, class0, class1, id_var){
  check <- require(checkmate)
  if (!check) stop ("Install the checkmate package")

  checkmate::assert_character(x = class0,
                              len = 1)
  checkmate::assert_character(x = class1,
                              len = 1)
  checkmate::assert_character(x = id_var,
                              len = 1)

  checkmate::assert_subset(c(class0, class1),
                           choices = names(DF))

  i <- 1

  DF[[id_var]] <- c(0, rep(NA, nrow(DF) - 1))

  while(sum(is.na(DF[[id_var]])) > 0){
    cross0 <- outer(DF[[class0]], DF[[class0]], `+`)
    match0 <- cross0 == DF[[class0]][i] & lower.tri(cross0)

    cross1 <- outer(DF[[class1]], DF[[class1]], `+`)
    match1 <- cross1 == DF[[class1]][i] & lower.tri(cross1)

    rows <- as.vector(which(match0 & match1, arr.ind = TRUE))
    if (length(rows)) DF[[id_var]][rows] <- i

    if (i == nrow(DF)) break else i <- i + 1
  }

  DF
}

assign_id(DF, "Nclass0", "Nclass1", "id")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Benjamin! This is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, this is a bit over the limit of my R skills. If I want turn this solution into function with a data.frame as input, what do I need to change? The inputmatrix has the same format as I gave in the example above.

Comment: I have tried to turn it into a function in this way:

Comment: I've tried to work it in as you posted, but there seems to be a problem with this solution."Error in DF[[id_var]] <- c(0, rep(NA, nrow(DF) - 1)) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace". I thought this was solved for by the 'nrow(DF) -1'. Do you maybe know why this error occurs?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the error.  Are you using the same data frame as in the sample, or your actual data frame?

Comment: I am still using the same data frame. Firstly, I get the following error: [link]https://i.imgsafe.org/fcff8100b3.png[/link]. I do not really know what these safeguards do, so if I leave this out it says: [link]https://i.imgsafe.org/fcffba7dd3.png[/link]. The end-game is to apply this function to this data frame, with 99 rows: [link]https://i.imgsafe.org/fd1a99e1f2.png[/link]

Comment: Turns out the links don't need a closing tag, sorry. Here are the working links: 1) [link]i.imgsafe.org/fcff8100b3.png 2) [link]i.imgsafe.org/fcffba7dd3.png 3) [link]i.imgsafe.org/fd1a99e1f2.png

Comment: Oh, I see now.  run `class(tree)`.  I bet you'll find that `tree` is a matrix and I did all my work on the assumption that `tree` was a data frame.

Comment: Sorry, that was really dumb. Thank you very much for your help, but unfortunately the script still does not work as desired. For the sample I provided above it works, but when I take another matrix the desired output is: [link]https://i.imgsafe.org/fd683ba342.png and the current output is [link]https://i.imgsafe.org/fd682b8da5.png . The parent in the desired output should match the id in the current.